# Expression for real part of ArcTanh(x) for x > 1

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, hyperbolic-functions

I know that the imaginary part of $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ is equal to $-i \pi/2$ for $x>1$. I am wondering if there is a known explicit expression for the real part?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer by inspection :

$$ \tanh^{-1}(x) = - i \frac{\pi}{2} + \tanh^{-1}(1/x) $$
for $x>1$.